# Boostrap 4 merge columns with alternating rows

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive

My bootstrap website has a layout made of two columns (on desktop). On each column, the content is statically stacked. The `div` on either side have different heights, like so:

```
A | B
A | D 
C | D
E | F
E
```

Right now, I've implemented this layout with two `col-6` and filling each one with the content `div`.

However, the breakpoints to mobile layout are only designed to stack the columns on top of each other, as in:

```
A
A
C
E
E
B
D
D
F
```

My problem is that in my illustrations above, the A `div` is relevant to the B `div`, not much to the C `div`. I'd love to implement my two-column desktop layout in a way where the mobile layout is:

```
A
A
B
C
D
D
E
E
F
```

On mobile, It effectively requires the inside of two columns to be merged by alternating the `div` they contain in a sequence of rows.  My pinky tells me that this won't be possible in bootstrap with two `col-6`. I'd love to avoid JavaScript and custom CSS wherever possible. Maybe the overall layout needs to be implemented without the `col-6`. Maybe `card-deck` can help, but I didn't find anything satisfactory.

---

The current code:

```html
         <div class="container">        
            <div class="row pl-sm-3 px-1">        
                <div class="col-md-6 pt-sm-4">
                  <div class="row pb-5 justify-content-center">
                    <h1 class="display-4 text-light">   
                        {{ $.Page.Title }}
                    </h1>
                  </div>
                  <div class="text-center">
                    {{ range .Params.pictures }}
                        <img ... >
                    {{end}}
                  </div>
                </div>        
                <div class="col-md-6 pl-3 pr-4">
                    <div class="mt-5 pt-5"></div>
                    <div class="card">
                    {{ range .Params.text}}
                        <div class="card-body">            
                            ...
                        </div>
                    {{end}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with bootstrap but you have to add the small CSS snippet below. After some testing I have got a solution for you where I also used the card grid.

If you want to use boostraps cards you can add the `card` class to every child element (with the col class).

```css
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .card-columns.column-2 {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-columns column-2 row d-sm-block">
    <div class="col-12 order-1">A<br/>A</div>
    <div class="col-12 order-2">C</div>
    <div class="col-12 order-1">B</div>
    <div class="col-12 order-2">D<br/>D</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-columns column-2 row d-sm-block">
    <div class="col-12 order-1">E<br/>E</div>
    <div class="col-12 order-2">F</div>
  </div>
</div>
```